# PHP Form posting to itself

Tags: php, html, forms

I have been trying to post some information contained in a form to itself. But I dont understand why its not working. It works when I post the data from a HTML page but when i post the information to itself it doesnt work.

Heres the code:

```
    $country =  isset($_POST['country']) ? $_POST['country'] : 'Belize';
$number_of_guests = isset($_POST['number_of_guests']) ? $_POST['number_of_guests'] : 2;
$from =  isset($_POST['price_range_from']) ? $_POST['price_range_from'] : 200;
$to =  isset($_POST['price_range_to']) ? $_POST['price_range_to'] : 2000;
```

When I post the information from the HTML form it works fine but on submitting to itself all the variables contain the value of "on". I dont know what I am missing or failing to implement correctly.

Here is the HTML form code:

```
<form action="find_results.php" method = "post">
    <strong>Select the Country</strong><br />
    <input id = 'c1' type= "radio" name= "country" checked/> Mexico <br />
    <input id = 'c2' type= "radio" name= "country" /> Belize <br />
    <input id = 'c3' type = "radio" name= "country" />Jamaica <br />
    <input id = 'c4' type = "radio" name= "country" />Thailand <br />
    <input id = 'c5' type = "radio" name= "country" />Turks & Caicos 
    <hr />

    <strong>Number of Guests</strong><br />
    <input id = 'n1' type= "radio" name= "number_of_guests" /> 2
    <input id = 'n2' type= "radio" name= "number_of_guests" /> 4
    <input id = 'n3' type= "radio" name= "number_of_guests" /> 6        
    <input id = 'n4' type= "radio" name= "number_of_guests" /> 8
    <input id = 'n5' type= "radio" name= "number_of_guests" /> 10+
    <hr />

    <strong>Price Range(From)</strong><br />
    <input id = 'from1' type= "radio" name= "price_range_from" /> 200
    <input id = 'from2' type= "radio" name= "price_range_from" /> 300
    <input id = 'from3' type= "radio" name= "price_range_from" /> 400
    <input id = 'from4' type= "radio" name= "price_range_from" /> 500
    <input id = 'from5' type= "radio" name= "price_range_from" /> 600 or More 
    <hr />

    <strong>Price Range(Upto)</strong><br />
    <input id = 'to1' type= "radio" name= "price_range_to" /> 500
    <input id = 'to2' type= "radio" name= "price_range_to" /> 600
    <input id = 'to3' type= "radio" name= "price_range_to" /> 700
    <input id = 'to4' type= "radio" name= "price_range_to" /> 800
    <input id = 'to5' type= "radio" name= "price_range_to" /> 900 or More
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: We would need to see a simplified version of your HTML form.  Please gut any styles, etc.  This process of creating something simpler might also help you find the root cause.

Comment: The code was in there, just not set as `code` in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have no values set in the form. How *does* this work when pointing to another page?

```
<input id = 'c1' type= "radio" name= "country" checked value='mexico' />
```

You do need to set a `value='something'` in the form so that the right data is passed. You are probably getting them as 'on' as the form element is being passed, but with no information in the `value` of it.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Fluffeh. The "values" of your particular tag is forwarded to your PHP code. Without the values you can't get the desired result.

```
<input id = 'c1' type= "radio" value="Mexico" name= "country" checked="checked" /> Mexico <br />
<input id = 'c2' type= "radio" value="Belize" name= "country" /> Belize <br />
```

In PHP, these values will be set for the country.